# Using and Graphing The Results of a Crosstab Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I am trying to do something that should be pretty simple - create a crosstab from some data and then manipulate/graph the results.

Take the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-   book/master/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')
df_out=df.pivot_table(index=["day"],values=["tip"], columns=["sex"],aggfunc=[np.sum])
```

Which gives me a pivot table of tips by day and looks like the following:

[image]

The problem is that I need a dataframe that looks like:

[image]

So I can interact with is and graph it

For example, I want to do

```
df[female]-df['male']
```

and I want to graph a seaborn factor plot of male and female by day

How do I get rid of the extraneous data here?  I tried dropping columns, resetting the index, etc, but can't seem to figure it out

Thanks for your help - been fighting with this all day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I remember running into this with other aggregate functions. Will the following work?

```
new_df = df['sum']['tip']
new_df['delta'] = new_df['female'] - new_df['male']
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method:

```
df_out = df_out['sum']['tip']
del df_out.columns.name
del df_out.index.name
```